# C Shared library: static variable initialization + global variable visibility among processes

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I want to modifiy an existing shared library so that it uses different memory management routines depending on the application using the shared library.

(For now) there will be two families of memory management routines:

- The standard malloc, calloc etc functions
- specialized versions of malloc, calloc etc

I have come up with a potential way of solving this problem (with the help of some people here on SO). There are still a few grey areas and I would like some feedback on my proposal so far.

This is how I intend to implement the modification:

1. Replace existing calls to malloc/calloc etc with my_malloc/my_calloc etc. These new functions will invoke correctly assigned function pointers instead of calling hard coded function names.
2. Provide a mechanism for the shared library to initialize the function pointers used by my_malloc etc to point to the standard C memory mgmt routines - this allows me to provide backward compatability to applications which depend on this shared library - so they don't have to be modified as well. In C++, I could have done this by using static variable initialization (for example) - I'm not sure if the same 'pattern' can be used in C.
3. Introduce a new idempotent function initAPI(type) function which is called (at startup) by the application that need to use different mem mgmt routines in the shared libray. The initAPI() function assigns the memory mgmt func ptrs to the appropriate functions.

Clearly, it would be preferable if I could restrict who could call initAPI() or when it was called - for example, the function should NOT be called after API calls have been made to the library - as this will change the memory mgmt routines. So I would like to restrict where it is called and by whom. This is an access problem which can be solved by making the method private in C++, I am not sure how to do this in C.

The problems in 2 and 3 above can be trivially resolved in C++, however I am constrained to using C, so I would like to solve these issues in C.

Finally, assuming that the function pointers can be correctly set during initialisation as described above - I have a second question, regarding the visibility of global variables in a shared library, accross different processes using the shared library. The function pointers will be implemented as global variables (I'm not too concerned about thread safety FOR NOW - although I envisage wrapping access with mutex locking at some point)* and each application using the shared library should not interfere with the memory management routines used for another application using the shared library.

I suspect that it is code (not data) that is shared between processes using a shlib - however, I would like that confirmed - preferably, with a link that backs up that assertion.

*Note: if I am naively downplaying threading issues that may occur in the future as a result of the 'architecture' I described above, someone please alert me!..

BTW, I am building the library on Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: "this will change the **money** mgmt routines" ... you better be extra careful :-)

Comment: @pmg: Oh snap!. Freudian slip there :)

Comment: Just a clarification: Is this a linux-specific question?

Comment: @Asaf Yes, I am building on Linux (as stated in the question). I suppose, I will add Linux and Ubuntu tags since they are relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm not entirely sure what the question being asked is, I will try to provide information that may be of use.

You've indicated [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), it is probably safe to assume you are also using the GNU toolchain.

---

GCC provides a *constructor* [function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) that causes a function to be called automatically before execution enters `main()`.  You could use this to better control when your library initialization routine, `initAPI()` is called.

```
void __attribute__ ((constructor)) initAPI(void);
```

In the case of library initialization, constructor routines are executed before `dlopen()` returns if the library is loaded at runtime or before `main()` is started if the library is loaded at load time.

---

The GNU linker has a `--wrap <symbol>` option which allows you to provide wrappers for system functions.

If you link with `--wrap malloc`, references to `malloc()` will redirect to `__wrap_malloc()` (which you implement), and references to `__real_malloc()` will redirect to the original `malloc()` (so you can call it from within your wrapper implementation).

Instead of using the `--wrap malloc` option to provide a reference to the original `malloc()` you could also dynamically load a pointer to the original `malloc()` using [`dlsym()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html).  You cannot directly call the original `malloc()` from the wrapper because it will be interpreted as a recursive call to the wrapper itself.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void * malloc(size_t size) {
   static void * (*func)(size_t) = NULL;
   void * ret;

   if (!func) {
      /* get reference to original (libc provided) malloc */
      func = (void *(*)(size_t)) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
   }

   /* code to execute before calling malloc */
   ...

   /* call original malloc */
   ret = func(size);

   /* code to execute after calling malloc */
   ...

   return ret;
}
```

I suggest reading [Jay Conrod's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891/jay-conrod) blog post entitled [*Tutorial: Function Interposition in Linux*](http://www.jayconrod.com/cgi/view_post.py?23) for additional information on replacing calls to functions in dynamic libraries with calls to your own wrapper functions.

Answer (score 1):

-1 for the lack of concrete questions. The text is long, could have been written more succintly, and it does not contain a single question-mark.

Now to address your problems:

Static data (what you call "global variables") of a shared library is per-process.  Your global variables in one process will not interfere with global variables in another process.  No need for mutexes.

In C, you cannot restrict[1] who can call a function. It can be called by anybody who knows its name or has a pointer to it. You can code `initAPI()` such that it visibly aborts the program (crashes it) if it is not the first library function called. You are library writer, you set the rules of the game, and you have NO obligation towards coders who do not respect the rules.

[1] You can declare the function with static, meaning it can be called by name only by the code within the same translation unit; it can still be called through a pointer by anybody who manages to obtain a pointer to it. Such functions are not "exported" from libraries, so this is not applicable to your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Achieving this:

> (For now) there will be two families of memory management routines:
>
> - The standard malloc, calloc etc functions
> - specialized versions of malloc, calloc etc

with dynamic libraries on Linux is *trivial*, and does *not* require the complicated scheme you have concocted (nor the `LD_PRELOAD` or `dlopen` suggested by @ugoren).

When you want to provide specialized versions of `malloc` and friends, simply link these routines into your main executable. Voila: your existing shared library will pick them up from there, *no modifications required*.

You could also build specialized `malloc` into e.g. `libmymalloc.so`, and put that library on the link line *before* `libc`, to achieve the same result.

The dynamic loader will use the first `malloc` it can see, and searches the list starting from the `a.out`, and proceeding to search other libraries in the same order they were listed on link command line.

UPDATE:

> On further reflection, I don't think what you propose will work.

Yes, it *will* work (I use that functionality *every* day, by linking `tcmalloc` into my main executable).

When your shared library (the one providing an API) calls `malloc` "behind the scenes", which (of possibly several) `malloc` implementations does it get? The *first* one that is visible to the dynamic linker. If you link a `malloc` implementation into `a.out`, that will be *the one*.

Comment: Sounds almost too good to be true. However, I'm not sure I fully understand your comments. If I define my own version of malloc etc which wrap around the custom funcs (palloc etc), will I not get a "multiple defined symbol" error during linking?. Otherwise, this is by far the simplest solution.

Comment: On further reflection, I don't think what you propose will work. You may have misunderstood my question. The shared library exposes an API which other apps call functions on (as expected). However calling functions in the API causes memory to be allocated/deallocated by the shared library. Apps are unaware of any memory mgmt being done "behind the scenes", by the shared library as a result of an API call. That is to say, the shared lib is currently HARD CODED to use the standard C memory management functions. I want to change this so that some APPS can change the functions used for memory mgmt

Comment: `@Homunculus Reticulli` - You can use function interposition to replace the memory management calls that are hard-coded in the shared library  with calls to your own wrapper functions without recompiling the shared library.  This would allow your applications to change the functions used for memory management as necessary.  I briefly touched on this concept in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8762134/203667)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough for you to require that your initialization function is:

- called from the main thread
- that the client may call it exactly once
- and that the client may provide the optional function pointers by parameter

Answer (score 0):

If different applications run in separate processes, it's quite simple to do using dynamic libraries.
The library can simply call malloc() and free(), and applications that want to override it could load another library, with alternative implementations for these libraries.
This can be done with the LD_PRELOAD environment variable.
Or, if your library is loaded with dlopen(), just load the malloc library first.

This is basically what tools such as valgrind, which replace malloc, do.

Comment: You *don't* need either `LD_PRELOAD` or `dlopen` to achieve desired result.